# How to return EmptyResult with a Status Code

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In ASP.NET MVC (with .net 4.0) I need to return a HTTP 500 result code and an empty page. Here are the ways I tried:

```
Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
return new EmptyResult();

Response.StatusCode = (int) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
return Content("");

return new HttpStatusCodeResult(500);
```

But it always returns a page (html) similar to this (with 500)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKI9C.png

Is this actually doable?

Comment: What's your custom error handling setup?  Both in `web.config` and any handlers that are configured in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an ASP.NET MVC action, you can return the result in any of the below format: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd410269(v=vs.98)

[image]

However, if you want to return the status code and show it, simply create a view and send the status to it and manipulate accordingly:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("~/Views/Test.cshtml", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

View:

```
@{ Layout = null; }


<h3>@Model</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to do it in `Application_Error` in Global

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

                Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed;
                Response.Write(string.Empty);
                Response.End();
            }
        }
```